# SharePoint Responsive Package PNP tools not able to enable feature in Package

Tags: 2013, powershell, solution-package, 2016, pnp

I am trying to implement  Responsive UI Package for SharePoint on-premises (2013 and 2016) from this link

http://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-2016

Now when I try to enable the feature using PS1 Script i get following error saying

> The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was  included, verify
>    that the path is correct and try again.

PS1 Script to Enable responsive Package is

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Tools/blob/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive/Enable-SPResponsiveUI.ps1

Comment: and one more thing i have check your script it is for SPO Solution

Answer (score 3):

Download and install the PS commands from http://aka.ms/officedevpnpcmdlets15. It should unpack the dll's to `C:\Program Files (x86)\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands`.

You then have to import the module which has this cmdlet.

Run 
`import-module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CorrectPath\OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell.V15.Commands.dll'`.

It should work then.

Comment: Akhoy as mentioned in previous comments Problem is resolved and we got the desired results...
Thanx for the Help...:)

Comment: @AnkitkumarMalde No problem. just placing it here for future readers. I'd also faced this problem and this resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Which ManagmentShell you are using bcoz for SPO its Defrrent   you have to run your script in to It "**Sharepoint Online Management Shell**"

and load below assembly

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

  Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: But i am working onPrem... So SPO Management shell would be required?

Comment: Connect-SPOnline so for it is compulsory  or else advice to change  Get Credntial Commnad from Script

Comment: Thanx SP for the help...
but the orignal script only worked for us... 
Issue was of loading Powershell Snappin and resolving that solved our issue.

Comment: Resolve issue or not???

Comment: you can vote me :)

Comment: your solution has issue.. It needs to connect to site so you need to connect to site using Connect-SPOnline...
So without connection we cannot apply SPOProvisioning Template..
But Appreciate your quick response...Thanx...

Comment: @S.P it is not only for O365. It is also for on prem. This is not the OOB cmdlet. It has been created by the OfficeDev team. https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/ConnectSPOnline.md